# Can the US President recognize Israel’s sovereignty over the Golan Heights for the USA or does that need an act of Congress?

Tags: united-states, president, congress, foreign-policy, separation-of-powers

President Trump has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1108772952814899200) that the USA should "fully recognize Israel’s Sovereignty over the Golan Heights" - directly contradicting [United Nations Security Council Resolution 497](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_497) from 1981.

Can the President effect that "on their own" or would it need some act of Congress?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Essentially, yes

By current precedent from the US Supreme Court, the US president not only has authority to recognize foreign nations, but *exclusive* authority. The pertinent case is [*Zivotofsky v. Kerry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zivotofsky_v._Kerry), where a couple wanted to list the birthplace of their child as "Jerusalem, Israel." At that time the State Department of the United States did not recognize Jerusalem as the capital of Israel, or in fact technically as part of Israel. Congress had passed [a law](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/PLAW-107publ228/pdf/PLAW-107publ228.pdf) allowing for precisely this case:

> RECORD OF PLACE OF BIRTH AS ISRAEL FOR PASSPORT PURPOSES.—For
>   purposes of the registration of birth, certification of nationality,
>   or issuance of a passport of a United States citizen born in the city
>   of Jerusalem, the Secretary shall, upon the request of the citizen or
>   the citizen’s legal guardian, record the place of birth as Israel.

When the case went to the Supreme Court, this portion of the law was found to be an unconstitutional restriction on the power of the President to recognize foreign nations, and the power of the president to do so [was reaffirmed.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/13-628)

> Held: 1. The President has the exclusive power to grant formal
>   recognition to a foreign sovereign. Pp. 6–26.

As such, it is within the US president's power to recognize the Golan Heights as being part of Israel, or not, without congressional support.

Comment: Can you quote the place in the constitution where this is stated (or implied)?

Comment: @einpoklum - I'm not saying it's right, only that it's the Supreme Court ruling. They tend to be determinative in the US, I think.

Comment: @Oble2.0 : I'm not arguing, I'm just asking for their reference. Surely the ruling must have one, right?

Comment: It's the bit that says “shall receive Ambassadors and other public Ministers."

Comment: Man, talk about a stretch.

Comment: Both @Obie2.0's answer and [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Curtiss-Wright_Export_Corp.) United States v. Curtiss-Wright Export Corp. refer to Article Two, Section 3, Clause 4 of the U.S. Constitution; which is short but the only part of the Constitution that lays out responsibility of foreign policy.  The Constitution only lays out declaring war and ratifying treaties as foreign policy authority for Congress.

Comment: @RWW: So wouldn't any reasonable interpretation be that it is Congress that can make decisions about recognizing sovereignty over territories? The sentence Obie2.0 quoted regards ceremonial duties, not powers.

Comment: @einpoklum no, because it's not a ceremonial duty.  It provides the President the authority to conduct the country's foreign affairs.  Additionaly, and not covered by the answer, the Department of Foreign Affairs (now State) was established by Congress as an executive department, which also falls under the President in Article II, section 2, clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution.

Comment: @RWW Except any such department can be eliminated by Congress at any time (though if they want to stop a likely veto, they'll need 2/3 majorities).  Congress can delegate powers, but only subject to certain restrictions; in particular it cannot forever surrender that power to any other branch.  So the power (validly) given to the department by Congress remains the power of Congress, but has been delegated to an executive branch (probably because they got tired of dealing with it themselves) to use in a specific fashion.

Comment: @einpoklum This is one of those decisions that falls under "unenumerated but required rights/powers", which is pretty common in major SCOTUS precedents.  The President's enumerated authority to receive ambassadors etc. is neutered if he does not have the power to decide *who* is an ambassador (or of *what*). To retain the specified power he must implicitly have the powers necessary to execute it.  This is also the origin of "executive privilege": a fiction deemed necessary for the office to function as specified and intended. "Badges and incidents of slavery" is a 13th amendment example.